# After remove first header line, numpy cannot delimit columns correctly

Tags: python, numpy

Without skip_header, numpy imports csv file correctly.

```
>>> data = np.genfromtxt('house_price.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None, encoding=None)
>>> print(data.shape)
(13581, 21)
>>> data[:3]
array([['Suburb', 'Address', 'Rooms', 'Type', 'Price', 'Method',
        'SellerG', 'Date', 'Distance', 'Postcode', 'Bedroom2',
        'Bathroom', 'Car', 'Landsize', 'BuildingArea', 'YearBuilt',
        'CouncilArea', 'Lattitude', 'Longtitude', 'Regionname',
        'Propertycount'],
       ['Abbotsford', '85 Turner St', '2', 'h', '1480000.0', 'S',
        'Biggin', '3/12/2016', '2.5', '3067.0', '2.0', '1.0', '1.0',
        '202.0', '', '', 'Yarra', '-37.7996', '144.9984',
        'Northern Metropolitan', '4019.0'],
       ['Abbotsford', '25 Bloomburg St', '2', 'h', '1035000.0', 'S',
        'Biggin', '4/02/2016', '2.5', '3067.0', '2.0', '1.0', '0.0',
        '156.0', '79.0', '1900.0', 'Yarra', '-37.8079', '144.9934',
        'Northern Metropolitan', '4019.0']], dtype='<U27')
```

With skip_header, numpy cannot delimit the columns

```
>>> data = np.genfromtxt('house_price.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None, skip_header=1,encoding=None)
>>> print(data.shape)
(13580,)
```

What am I missing? Is it possible to get a shape of (13581, 21) when using   `skip_header=1` or `names=True`

Comment: We might need to see the first few lines of the file.  Or you could help us by showing the `data.dtype` for the first case.

Comment: @hpaulj I've updated the question, would you please take a loot at it?

Comment: With a first line like that, we usually try to use `names=True` along with the `dtype=None`.  That way those strings are used as field names.  The `(13581, 21)` array is probably a string dtype.  `(13580,)` is a 1d array with a compound dtype, a `structured array`.

Comment: @hpaulj Is it possible to get a shape of (13581, 21) when using skip_header=1 or names=True

Comment: What `dtype` do you want?  What are you going to do with this array?  Have you considered `pandas`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.genfromtxt('house_price.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None, encoding=None)` gives you a regular (2D) numpy array where all elements have the same dtype (`'<U27'` in your case).

With `skip_header` you get a **structured** (1D) array, where each entry is a record of 21 elements (fields):

```
data[:1]
#array([('Abbotsford', '68 Studley St', 2, 'h', -1, 'SS', 'Jellis', '3/09/2016', 2.5, 3067, 2, 1, 1, 126, nan, -1, 'Yarra City Council', -37.8014, 144.9958, 'Northern Metropolitan', 4019)],
#      dtype=[('f0', '<U18'), ('f1', '<U27'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<U1'), ('f4', '<i4'), ('f5', '<U2'), ('f6', '<U27'), ('f7', '<U10'), ('f8', '<f8'), ('f9', '<i4'), ('f10', '<i4'), ('f11', '<i4'), ('f12', '<i4'), ('f13', '<i4'), ('f14', '<f8'), ('f15', '<i4'), ('f16', '<U30'), ('f17', '<f8'), ('f18', '<f8'), ('f19', '<U26'), ('f20', '<i4')])
```

Here, each 'column' (so to speak) has its own dtype. So numpy did a great job delimiting the columns, you just don't see it looking at the output of `shape`.

With `names=True` (without skipping the header) you get the same result (structured array), but with proper field names instead of 'f0' ... 'f20'.

---

You may want you have a look at [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). You can create a dataframe by

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('house_price.csv')
```

This gives you a dataframe of 13581 rows and 21 columns, each with its own data type. If you should need the data as numpy array, you can get them from the dataframe with `df.to_numpy()`:

```
df.to_numpy()[:2]
#array([['Abbotsford', '68 Studley St', 2, 'h', nan, 'SS', 'Jellis',
#        '3/09/2016', 2.5, 3067.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 126.0, nan, nan,
#        'Yarra City Council', -37.8014, 144.9958,
#        'Northern Metropolitan', 4019.0],
#       ['Abbotsford', '85 Turner St', 2, 'h', 1480000.0, 'S', 'Biggin',
#        '3/12/2016', 2.5, 3067.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 202.0, nan, nan,
#        'Yarra City Council', -37.7996, 144.9984,
#        'Northern Metropolitan', 4019.0]], dtype=object)
```

or use `df.to_records()` to get a structured numpy array.